# Can I turn off global menu only in Nautilus?

Tags: unity, nautilus

According to post #15 of [this Ubuntu Forums thread about Nautilus being slow](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643832&highlight=nautilus%20slow&page=2), turning off global menu speeds Nautilus up significantly. This is certainly true for me, as running Nautilus as root makes it a few times (!) faster (with no gnome-scripts installed, cache cleared, Dropbox turned off).

Now, I like the global menu--but I also want Nautilus to be fast! **Is there a way to turn off the global menu only for Nautilus?**

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the global menu in Nautilus.

1. Open a terminal and type `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`
2. Find the line `Exec=nautilus %U` and change it to `Exec=UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 nautilus %U`
3. Save and exit
4. Kill Nautilus by opening Nautilus, press Alt + F2, type xkill, click the Nautilus window.
5. Launch Nautilus again. No more global menu.

Now launching nautilus should have the global menu disabled.

### EDIT

I just realised that this method works with other programs but not with Nautilus bacause Nautilus is launched at startup. This is not a direct answer to your question but if you want a faster file manager, you might consider installing Thunar.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The icon just keeps pulsing and nautilus won't open...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

- Create a litte script in **(/usr/bin)**, go to the terminal and type:

  `cd /usr/bin`

  `sudo gedit nautilusappmenu.sh`
- In the script add these lines:

  `#! /bin/bash`
  `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`
  `nautilus -n`
- Change the permissions to 775:

  `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/nautilusappmenu.sh`
- Edit the nautilus desktop file in **/etc/xdg/autostart/** folder.
  First make a backup of the .desktop,in the terminal type:

  `cd /etc/xdg/autostart`

  `sudo cp nautilus-autostart.desktop nautilus-autostart.desktop.bak`

  `sudo gedit nautilus-autostart.desktop`

  Find the line **"Exec=nautilus -n"** and change it to **"Exec=/usr/bin/nautilusappmenu.sh"**

[image]

- Finally log out and log in to see the changes.

*If anything goes wrong remember you have a backup of the nautilus-autostart.desktop file, or just edit the line "Exec=/usr/bin/nautilusappmenu.sh" to "Exec=nautilus -n" from any TTY.*

Hope this will solve your problem.

Regards.